# Object.assign() with Complex object Angular2 ngrx/store

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, ngrx

```
import { Blog } from './app.model';
import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as _ from 'underscore';

export const LOAD_BLOGS = 'LOAD_BLOGS';
export const SAVE_COMMENT = 'SAVE_COMMENT';

export interface AppState {
    blogs : Blog[]
}

export const initialState : AppState = {
    blogs : []
};

var a;

export const reducer = (state : AppState = initialState, action :Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_BLOGS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                blogs : action.payload
            });

        case SAVE_COMMENT:
            const {title, comment} = action.payload;
            return state.blogs.map(states =>{
                    if(states.title === action.payload.title){
                    console.log(states);
                    return Object.assign({}, states ,{ comment : [...states.comment , action.payload.comment]});
                }
                return Object.assign({}, states);
            });

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**STORE BEFORE SAVE_COMMENT ACTION**

```
{blogs : [{id: 1, "title" : "one", "comment" : ["oneC", "twoC"]}, {id: 2, "title" : "two", "comment" : ["oneC", "TwoC"]}]}
```

**STORE AFTER SAVE_COMMENT ACTION WITH COMMENT "ThreeC" to blog with title "two"**

```
[{id: 1, "title" : "one", "comment" : ["oneC", "twoC"]},{id: 2, "title" : "two", "comment" : ["oneC", "TwoC", "ThreeC"]}]
```

outter blogs object which should contain array of objects is not there, instead there is just an array of object with updated blogs.

Comment: If you know about `Object.assign()` then what have you tried?

Comment: If it's urgent, please make the question as clear as possible, instead of adding a text that it's urgent.

Comment: I have updated the question, please have look..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you put some simple console.logs in your reducer function and the for loop in your details function to see what it is doing.

Your problem is that you have a map in your reducer function that iterates over every blog, and then in your details function you again loop on all blogs and once you find a match return the match.

This means you loop on every blog post and replace it with the one that matches the blog title (you'll hit `return Object.assign({},state,c);`).

You can solve in many ways, but if you like your code structure, you could pass just that blog's state into details and remove the for loop.